# Submenu won't go horizontal

Tags: css

I know others have asked this question, but I just cannot get my submenu to go horizontal.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="main">
<header>
<h1 id="hheading">Australian Design Architects</h1>
<img src="logo2.gif" alt="ADA LOGO" width="100" height="100" id="himg" />
<nav>
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
<li><code><a href="index.html"> <!--id="home"-->Home</a></code></li>
<li><code><a href="about.html">About Us</a></code></li>
<li><code><a href="index.html" class="MenuBarItemSubmenu">Portfolio</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Heritage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Renovations/Additions</a></li>
    </ul>
</code></li>
<li><code><a href="services.html">Services</a></code></li>
<li><code><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></code></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

and here's my css:

```
nav {
font-size: 18px;
position: absolute;
padding-top: 50px;
padding-left: 140px;
padding-bottom:50px;
zoverflow:visible;
}

nav ul{
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
zclear: both;
}

nav ul li{
float:left;
display:inline;
}

nav ul li:after{
content:'|';
}

nav li a {
font-family:'flux_architect_regular', sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
}

nav ul ul li a{ 
border:1px solid #000;
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
overflow:hidden;
zwidth:550px;
zleft:0;
zlist-style:none;
zfloat: left;
zclear: both;
zmargin-left:-200px;
zpadding:100px;
}
```

and here's the css from dreamweaver:

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 100%;
cursor: default;
width: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarActive
{
z-index: 1000;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 100%;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
cursor: pointer;
width: 9.2em;
float: left;
}

#MenuBar1 li code #home {
text-align: center;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 100%;
z-index: 1020;
cursor: default;
width: 8.2em;
position: absolute;
left: -1000em;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
left: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
width: 8.2em;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
position: absolute;
margin: -5% 0 0 95%;

}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
left: auto;
top: 0;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
cursor: pointer;
padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
color: #333;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
background-color: #6a8c3f;
color: #FFF;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover,   ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
background-color: #6a8c3f;
color: #FFF;
}


ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRight.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 95% 50%;
 }

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
 {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1010;
filter:alpha(opacity:0.1);
 }

@media screen, projection
{
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
{
    display: inline;
    f\loat: left;
    background: #FFF;
}
}
```

I need this for my course assignment, so please help.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to more specifically indicate the behaviour you're trying to achieve? Your words of "go horizontal" are rather vague.

Comment: Sorry about the being too vague. I have horizontal menu and on one of the items in the menu there's a submenu. This submenu won't display inline, no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0):

hey i have created fiddle for you please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/zL2xR/) 
http://jsfiddle.net/cooolkiran/zL2xR/

```
nav {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 140px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    zoverflow:visible;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    zclear: both;
}
nav ul li {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
nav ul li:after {
    content:'|';
}
nav ul li:last-child:after {
    content:'';
}
nav li a {
    font-family:'flux_architect_regular', sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #333;
    padding:5px;
}
nav ul ul {
    display:none;
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:auto;
    left: 56px;
}
nav ul li li {
    display:inline-block;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    border:1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the fiddle. I really appreciate it. You're not going to believe this but it still won't work. I made all the necessary adjustments, I even commented out the bit in the css for nav where I have a bunch of stuff set to display:block, and it still goes vertically instead of horizontally. It's very frustrating. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: why don't u post a screenshot.

Comment: I can't add an image as my reputation is only one and needs to be at least ten. Could I email it to you?

Comment: yeah please.. cooolkiran@gmail.com